# Unable to get the element values dynamically using xslt inside for-each-group , group-starts-with and element name having numbers

Tags: xml, xslt-3.0

Unable to get the values of elements which is having names with numbers in xsl

```
<UserDefinedFields>
  <UserField1>yui</UserField1>
  <UserField2>yui</UserField2>
 <UserField3>yui</UserField3>
 ..
 <UserField10>yui</UserField10>
</UserDefinedFields>
```

xslt which I tried is:

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="/UserDefinedFields/*" group-starts-with="UserField">
  <xsl:variable name="ind" select="position()"/>
  <xsl:element name="UDField$ind">
    <xsl:value-of select="/UserDefinedFields/concat('UserField',$ind})"/>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:for-each-group>
```

Need below result:

```
 <UserDefinedFields>
      <UDField1>yui1</UDField1>
      <UDField2>yuiyh</UDField2>
     <UDField3>yuijk</UDField3>
     ..
     <UDField10>yuirt</UDField10>
    </UserDefinedFields>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to apply the value of that `$ind` number to the element name, you need to wrap it in curly braces, and [Attribute Value Template](https://www.w3.org/TR/2017/REC-xslt-30-20170608/#attribute-value-templates):

```
<xsl:element name="UDField{$ind}">
```

Based upon the input XML and the snippet provided, it isn't clear why you need `xsl:for-each-group`. It seems that `xsl:for-each` with a predicate on the `@select` to select those child elements of `UserDefinedFields` who's names start with `UserField` should be sufficient:

```
<xsl:for-each select="/UserDefinedFields/*[starts-with(local-name(), 'UserField')]">
  <xsl:variable name="ind" select="position()"/>
  <xsl:element name="UDField{$ind}">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I am able to get the result. Could you please tell when we can use for-each-group

Comment: You are free to use it, if you want. But for this particular use case, it didn't seem that it would buy you much and would make the rest of the code a little more complicated. Typically you use `xsl:for-each-group` when you need to group records by something, to make it easier to calculate aggregate stats or generate grouped output (think of nested structures by the grouped-key, or table of contents)